# error: no space left on device when saving file (but there is space)

Tags: unix, storage, ruby

I am implementing in ruby however when I want to save my work I get

```
"Opening output file: no space left on device, /afs/edu/usr7/ael/p\
rivate/RUBY/inc.rb"
```

When I checked if I got any space using df -h this is what appeared:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root
                       55G   21G   32G  39% /
tmpfs                 1.9G   36K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   60M  400M  14% /boot
AFS                   8.6G     0  8.6G   0% /afs
```

It seems like I do have space, I dont know why I cant save though. What seems to be the prolem here?

df -i shows:

```
Filesystem            Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_root
                     3645440 571814 3073626   16% /
tmpfs                 490631      3  490628    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             128016     45  127971    1% /boot
AFS                  9000000      0 9000000    0% /afs
```

looks like I have available inodes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with AFS, which is a networked file system. I suspect that you are probably bumping into a quota limit. You will need to work with the administrator of that service.

Answer (score 1):

Check your inode usage via `df -i` - on a standard partition, you could have exhausted your inode limits on the filesystem. This most often happens when you're storing lots of small files (for example, cache).

Your `df -h` output suggests that you have zero bytes in use on that partition, so this could also be access or mount permissions on the underlying AFS volume. Check that the credentials used for the mount have write access, and that the underlying volume has enough space.

Comment: how will your second paragraph help? And how can I manipulate the access I get?

Comment: Manipulate suggests that you don't have administrative access to the host providing the share. If that is the case, you should contact the administrator of that host.